# How Do I add turn based combat on these scripts in unity 2d?

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on a game and I am totally stuck on what to do here. My problem is that I want a turn based combat for my game like a pool game or tic tac toe or anything. I am working on local multiplayer where screen needs to be divided in two parts. Upper part for player1 and lower part for player2, So far I am also not able to do that. Each player will get 5 turns. Player will take turn one by one until all 5 are taken.

The controller script on my both object is :

```
Vector2 startPos, endPos, direction;
Rigidbody2D myRigidbody2D;
public float Power = 10f;
public float maxDrag = 5f;

void Start() {
     myRigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
 }

void OnMouseDown() {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
         startPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
     }
 }

void OnMouseUp () {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
         endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
         direction = startPos - endPos;
         myRigidbody2D.isKinematic = false;
         Vector2 force = startPos - endPos;
         Vector2 clampedForce = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(force, maxDrag) * Power;
         myRigidbody2D.AddForce (clampedForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
     }
 }
```

There is an empty gameobject named `battlehandler` that should handle the turns but I am stuck; the script is:

```
public enum gameState { Start,p1Turn,p2Turn,Won,Lost}
public class battleSsystem : MonoBehaviour {

public gameState state;
int randomTurn = 0;

int p1TurnCount = 5;
int p2TurnCount = 5;
bool flag = true;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    state = gameState.Start;
    StartCoroutine(setupBattle());
    randomTurn = Random.Range(1, 1);
    if (randomTurn == 1) {
        state = gameState.p1Turn;
        Debug.Log("P1 Turn");
        p1TurnCount--;
    } else if (randomTurn == 2)
    {
        state = gameState.p2Turn;
        p2TurnCount++;
        Debug.Log("P2 Turn");
    }
}

private void Update() {
    if (state == gameState.p1Turn) {
        p1Enable();
        p2Disable();
        if (flag) {
            p1TurnCount--;
            flag = false;
        }
        Debug.Log("p1 has left: " + p1TurnCount);
    } else if (state == gameState.p2Turn) {
        p1Disable();
        p2Enable();
        Debug.Log("p2 has left: " + p2TurnCount);
    }
    if (p1TurnCount < p2TurnCount) {
        state = gameState.p2Turn;
    } else {
        state = gameState.p1Turn;
    }
}

IEnumerator setupBattle() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
}

IEnumerator p1Turn() {
    p1Enable();
    p2Disable();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
}

void p2Disable() {
    GameObject[] objs;
    objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("p2");
    foreach (GameObject p2 in objs) {
        p2.GetComponent<ballController>().enabled = false;
    }
}

void p2Enable() {
    GameObject[] objs;
    objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("p2");
    foreach (GameObject p2 in objs) {
        p2.GetComponent<ballController>().enabled = true;
    }
}

void p1Disable() {
    GameObject[] objs;
    objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("p1");
    foreach (GameObject p1 in objs) {
        p1.GetComponent<ballController>().enabled = false;
    }
}

void p1Enable() {
    GameObject[] objs;
    objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("p1");
    foreach (GameObject p1 in objs) {
        p1.GetComponent<ballController>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I want to select a random turn at first then change the turn after the selected player has made their turn.

How should I tackle this problem?

I am making a turn based game and I want to switch turns after a user is done back and forth. I cant use update as it will restart the turn every frame.

```
public enum gameState { Start,p1Turn,p2Turn,Won,Lost}
public class battleSsystem : MonoBehaviour { public gameState 
state; int randomTurn = 0;

int p1TurnCount = 5;
int p2TurnCount = 5;
bool flag = true;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start() {
    state = gameState.Start;
    StartCoroutine(setupBattle());
    randomTurn = Random.Range(1, 3);
    if (randomTurn == 1) {
        state = gameState.p1Turn;
    } else if (randomTurn == 2) {
        state = gameState.p2Turn;  
    }
    if (state == gameState.p1Turn) {
        Debug.Log("P1 Turn start");
        p1Turn();
    }
    if (state == gameState.p2Turn) {
        Debug.Log("P2 Turn start");
        p2Turn();
    }
}

IEnumerator setupBattle() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
}

void p1Turn() {
    Debug.Log("inside p1 turn");
    p1Enable();//enables the player 1 controller
    p2Disable();//disables player 2 controller
}
 
void p2Turn() {
    Debug.Log("inside p2 turn");
    p2Enable();//enables the player 2 controller
    p1Disable();//disables player 1 controller
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One pattern I have used very successfully in multiple turn-based projects is to implement each state as a separate GameObject which includes all the scripts and sub-objects which are supposed to be active during that state.

At game start, deactivate all those state GameObjects except the initial state. To transition to a different state, just deactivate the current one and activate the object for the new state. You might want to do this via a central StateManager game object, so the states don't need to know too much about each other.

Any logic which needs to be performed when exiting a state can be put into `OnDisable` methods of its scripts. Any logic which needs to be performed when entering a state can be put into `OnEnable`.

Comment: I want the object to stay on game. I just want the controller to be disable. I am gonna explain how its working for me. I have 2 game objects on upper side as player 1 and 2 on lower side as player2. Player 1 takes its turn and then disables all its controller then shift the turn which is working fine but my main game idea that i am having difficulty to implement. I am looking in to it and hopefully it will work. Thank You for your help

Comment: @Nomi Keep in mind that the object with the script which takes input does not necessarily need to be the same which is affected by the input. You can rewrite your player input controller to store the object controlled by it in a variable and then assign the player game-object to the controller via inspector. This pattern is actually much closer to what a "Controller" is supposed to be doing [by the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller): control another object. (Seriously, those tutorial youtubers need to stop calling every script a "controller").

Comment: ngl your explanation went over my head but I will definitely look more in to it