# How to add turn based system like of snooker or pool game in unity2d?

Tags: unity

How can I add a turn based system like a pool or snooker game in unity that waits for a player turn to be over before moving it to other player in local multiplayer?

How can I determine when the turn is over?

Comment: This question is a bit lacking in details. If you show us what you've done so far, an answer can help you with just the one step you're missing. But if we can't see any of your work so far, then this question basically asks a stranger to make a complete solution from scratch — and that's a tall order that might lead to this question going unanswered.

Comment: Also, you don't need to keep putting "...in unity2d" in your question titles. There is no engine called "unity2d". It's just "Unity", and that's already specified in your question tags. Turn-taking mechanics don't care whether your rendering is 2D or 3D, so that part is irrelevant.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195100/how-do-i-add-turn-based-combat-on-these-scripts-in-unity-2d

Comment: What do you want a reader to glean from that link? Are you saying that linked question has the details, and this question is just a duplicate?

Comment: Yes because no one answered it and I tried to add it more simple so maybe some one can simply explain me how to do it and then I can use that method

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate then. Please post each question just once. If you want to update your question, edit it, do not post new copies, leaving unanswered dead ends to confuse future searches.