# How do I keep switching turns/states until a result is determined in unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a turn based game and I want to switch turns after a user is done back and forth.
I cant use update as it will restart the turn every frame. My code is:

```
public enum gameState { Start,p1Turn,p2Turn,Won,Lost}
```

public class battleSsystem : MonoBehaviour
{
public gameState state;
int randomTurn = 0;

```
int p1TurnCount = 5;
int p2TurnCount = 5;
bool flag = true;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    state = gameState.Start;
     StartCoroutine(setupBattle());
    randomTurn = Random.Range(1, 3);
    if (randomTurn == 1)
    {
        state = gameState.p1Turn;
    }
      
    else if (randomTurn == 2)
    {
        state = gameState.p2Turn;  
    }

    if (state == gameState.p1Turn)
    {
        Debug.Log("P1 Turn start");
        p1Turn();
    }

    if (state == gameState.p2Turn)
    {
        Debug.Log("P2 Turn start");
        p2Turn();
    }
}

IEnumerator setupBattle()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0f);
}

void p1Turn()
{
    Debug.Log("inside p1 turn");
    p1Enable();//enables the player 1 controller
    p2Disable();//disables player 2 controller
}
 
void p2Turn()
{
    Debug.Log("inside p2 turn");
    p2Enable();//enables the player 2 controller
    p1Disable();//disables player 1 controller
}
```

So now this code at start will setup the battles. For now the function is empty. Then it will select a random turn and change the state according to it. This will only work once but i want it to work until p1TurnCount and p2TurnCount is 0.
How can i run this back and forth?

Comment: Is this still solving the same core problem as [your previous question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/195100/39518)? If so, would you like to edit that question to update it with the latest details, instead of posting a new question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I add turn based combat on these scripts in unity 2d?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/195100/how-do-i-add-turn-based-combat-on-these-scripts-in-unity-2d)